# Mingw and SDL2 include (VS code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

So,
I try to use the **SDL2 library** in a C++ project (on **Visual Studio Code**). I use **Mingw** to compilate, but I keep having error :

```
D:\Path/View/View.cpp:20: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
D:\Path/View/View.cpp:21: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
D:\Path/View/View.cpp:22: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
D:\Path/View/View.cpp:25: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
l:/common/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I have the following **task** to *build* my project (With the SDL library include in mingw folder):

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-g","main.cpp",
                "-o","main.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also try the following :

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-I","D:/Path/SDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/include",
                "-L","D:/Path/SDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/lib",
                "-lSDL2main",
                "-lSDL2",
                "-g","main.cpp",
                "-o","main.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Intellisense work fine with the **include path** : "D:/Path/SDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/include".
I dont see where I miss something :I

Answer (score 0):

I get the problem, apparently the order of **mingw** flags is important (dont found why thought) :

```
"args": [
    "-Wall",
    "-g","main.cpp",
    "-o","main.exe",
    "-lmingw32",
    "-lSDL2main",
    "-lSDL2"
],
```

Or with the path (-I for include and -L for library)

Answer (score -1):

After Including SDL in your project, you need to undefine SDL's main function, in C/C++ you can do it by adding the following code under your include for SDL: "#undef main", this undefines SDL's main function, which is there for some reason that I do not know, you also need to link against SDL2.dll using the -lSDL2 flag, however if you have done these steps and still get the error, you may need to inspect your code a little closer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).