# undefined reference to "SDL_..."

Tags: c++, sdl

i started learning sdl2 today but when i try to run my code, it throws a ton of 'undefined reference to `SDL_'

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "inc/SDL.h"
int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(1920, 1080, 0, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, 1920/2, 1080/2);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

any help is appreciated. thanks

errors:

```
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\xisha\Desktop\C++\firstproject\main.cpp -o C:\Users\xisha\Desktop\C++\firstproject\main.exe
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\xisha\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8tOsJ6.o: in function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderDrawPoint'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/xisha/Desktop/C++/firstproject/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main':
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:70: undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

Comment: ***C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\xisha\Desktop\C++\firstproject\main.cpp -o C:\Users\xisha\Desktop\C++\firstproject\main.exe*** You are not linking to the SDL libraries at all. You compile `main.cpp` and don't link to any library other than the ones your  toolchain adds by default.

Comment: ***i try to run my code*** That is part of your problem. code-runner does not link to any libraries or support more than 1 source file. And since a change to make it support libraries is global its not a good solution. It's best to forget code-runner exists for c or c++ based projects and instead use the default build method or learn CMake.

Comment: Learn about the 3 important json files here; [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) then look at this answer about linking to sdl using a tasks.json [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477654/mingw-and-sdl2-include-vs-code/51479572#51479572](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477654/mingw-and-sdl2-include-vs-code/51479572#51479572)